# Activity breakpoint can work together with ViewModel's lifecycle breakpoint?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I use Architecture Component LiveCycle Event

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
fun onCreate() {
    fetchData()
}
```

And I have in my Activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list)
    (application as MainApplication).component.inject(viewModel)
    setupLiveCycleModel()
    setupList()
}
```

If I put breakpoints in both my Activity's `onCreate` and View Model's `onCreate`, it will only break at my Activity's `onCreate` and will skip breaking at View Model's `onCreate`. (but the code still get executed).

If I remove my Activitiy's `onCreate` breakpoint, then the View Model's `onCreate` breakpoint is now triggered.

Why is this so? Can I have both triggered without need to turn off one?

Comment: Interesting, can you put logging code in both method and observe the thread id in logcat? usually I encountered debugging problem like this (not related to Lifecycle) if the code is executed in different thread.

Comment: I use `Thread.currentThread().name` to print the name. Both show they are on Main thread.

Comment: I even try `Debug.waitForDebugger()` on the ViewModel, it is not breaking if I have a breakpoint in my `onCreate`